Issue type hinting set of child objects in Python
Mypy is flagging an issue with my code that is really confusing to me. Here's a snippet of code that illustrates the issue. Note that this is running in Python 3.12.3 and mypy 1.10.0
class A:
    pass


class B(A):
    pass


def func_of_a(var1: A) -> None:
    pass


def func_of_set_of_a(var1: set[A]) -> None:
    pass


a = A()
b = B()


b1: B = B()
func_of_a(b1)  # mypy does not flag this as being an issue (as expected)


set_of_a: set[A] = {a}
set_of_b: set[B] = {b}

func_of_set_of_a(set_of_a)   # mypy does not flag this as being an issue (as expected)

func_of_set_of_a(set_of_b)  # mypy flags this as an issue

mypy is flagging func_of_set_of_a(set_of_b) as being problematic with the following error:

error: Argument 1 to "func_of_set_of_a" has incompatible type "set[B]"; expected "set[A]"  [arg-type]

I don't understand why this is being flagged. func_of_a expects an object of type A and will also accept an object of any child class of A. Shouldn't func_of_set_of_a behave similarly? func_of_set_of_a expects a set[A], but shouldn't it also accept a set of objects of a child class of A? I know I can change the type hint to set[A] | set[B], but that would make my code unwieldy since in my actual use case, class A has many child classes.
What am I missing here?
I tried googling but could not find any info on this. Unless I'm missing it, the official Python documentation also does not address this.

There is a pretty good discussion here: https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#covariance-and-contravariance

TL;DR set (and other mutable containers) are invariant. This matters when you manipulate the container in supertypes. The following is dangerous if the type-checker doesn't warn you: set_of_b: set[B] = {b}; set_of_a: set[A] = set_of_b; set_of_a.add(A())

In general mutable types should be invariant while immutable collections can be covariant. You test this by changing your sets to frozensets.

To illustrate the problem if mypy decided to allow your code, let's take a look at a modified example. I have:

added a # type: ignore to silence the relevant flag.
added method say_hello for B
made func_of_set_of_a now perform var1.add(A())
added the below to the end of the program

for b in set_of_b:
    b.do_y()

When we run mypy on the above file, there are no errors reported. However, at runtime, we get:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mishac/dev/python/784/main.py", line 34, in <module>
    b.say_hello()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'say_hello'

This error occurs because in mypy's eyes, when the programmer is saying func_of_set_of_a receives a var1: set[A], that user wants to be able to write As to and read As from var1. This is the contract of the set container.
And while set_of_b does support reading As (since every B is an A), it does not support writing As. This is because set_of_b, as part of that same set contract, must support reading Bs. If an A was written, there would be no way to force that into an instance of its subclass B during a followup read!
Therefore, any behavior specific to Bs (like do_y) will fail. In order to prevent runtime errors, mypy prevents any set[B] from being interpreted as a set[A], like you are doing in func_of_set_of_a(set_of_b). So without the # type: ignore, the error is caught before runtime.
Since there is no way to turn set[B] into set[A] here, we can instead make the datatype stricter. The func_of_set_of_b invocation that caused the above error needed to be able to write (add) to our set. If we make our sets immutable via frozenset, we can see there are no errors. If you happen to write a func_of_set_of_b attempting mutation of var1 in the future, mypy will then flag it.

Thank you for the very clear answer! Changing to a frozenset was exactly what I needed. Also learned a lot about covariance/contravariance/invariance.

from typing import TypeVar, Set

# Define a TypeVar with an upper bound of A
T = TypeVar('T', bound=A)

class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

def func_of_a(var1: A) -> None:
    pass

def func_of_set_of_a(var1: Set[T]) -> None:
    pass

a = A()
b = B()

b1: B = B()
func_of_a(b1)  # mypy does not flag this as being an issue (as expected)

set_of_a: Set[A] = {a}
set_of_b: Set[B] = {b}

func_of_set_of_a(set_of_a)  # mypy does not flag this as being an issue (as expected)
func_of_set_of_a(set_of_b)  # mypy should now not flag this as an issue


This works, but creates a cascade of downstream changes. Why is this needed in the first place?

Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. It looks like you've been here a while, but this is your first answer. In general, code-only answers are discouraged. This, in addition to the lack of code formatting, is getting you downvoted. You might consider editing your question to add details and format your code
